# Variables inside a function with bad values - Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, variables, scope, size

I'm trying to change an image size based on a multiplier factor. The function is been called in a onmouseover event and recover  the previous size of the imagen in onmouseout.

```
function cambiar_img_ampliando(imagen, inout, porcentaje)
{
    //Description of arguments:
    //(image element, onmouseover or onmouseout, % of size increase)
    var multiplicador = porcentaje/100; //Multiplier
    var alto = imagen.offsetHeight;
    var ancho = imagen.offsetWidth;
    if (inout==1) //onmouseover
    {
        var nuevo_alto = alto+(alto*multiplicador);
        var nuevo_ancho = ancho+(ancho*multiplicador);

        //Change the image size
        imagen.style.height = nuevo_alto+"px";
        imagen.style.width = nuevo_ancho+"px";

        //Adjust image position > To keep it center
        var top = (alto*multiplicador)/2;
        var left = (ancho*multiplicador)/2;
        imagen.style.top="-"+top+"px";
        imagen.style.left="-"+left+"px";
    }
    if (inout==0) //onmouseout
    {
       //Recover the original image size
       imagen.style.height = alto+"px";
       imagen.style.width = ancho+"px";

       //Replace image
       imagen.style.top="0px";
       imagen.style.left="0px";
    }
}
```

The problem happens in the `inout==0` section (when onmouseout calls the function with `0` value for `inout` argument):
`alto` and `ancho` variables doesn't recover the original size values of the imagen correctly. It seems get the values of the variables `nuevo_alto` and `nuevo_ancho`. It's very strange... because if I set the values of `ancho` and "alto" manually (to a certain pixels) it runs ok, I've been checking all scope of variables and at this moment I can't understand why this line: `imagen.style.height = alto+"px"`
doesn't recover the original height value of the imagen...

Is it possible that the line:
`imagen.style.height = nuevo_alto+"px";`
changing the value of `"alto"` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should

1. use no var:

   ```
   alto = imagen.offsetHeight;
   ancho = imagen.offsetWidth;
   ```

   Instead of `var ...`, that way your variables will be in global scope.
2. These variables are set *every* time the function is called, which means they always have the current image dimensions and not the orginal one. So you have to set them *only* on `mouseover` and not on `mouseout`:

   ```
   if (inout==1) //onmouseover
   {
        // Save original image size
        if (!alto) {
            alto = imagen.offsetHeight;
            ancho = imagen.offsetWidth;
        }
   }
   ```

Putting all together:

```
alto = 0;
ancho = 0;

function cambiar_img_ampliando(imagen, inout, porcentaje)
{
    //Description of arguments:
    //(image element, onmouseover or onmouseout, % of size increase)
    var multiplicador = porcentaje/100; //Multiplier
    if (inout==1) //onmouseover
    {
        // Save original image size
        if (!alto) {
            alto = imagen.offsetHeight;
            ancho = imagen.offsetWidth;
        }

        var nuevo_alto = alto+(alto*multiplicador);
        var nuevo_ancho = ancho+(ancho*multiplicador);

        //Change the image size
        imagen.style.height = nuevo_alto+"px";
        imagen.style.width = nuevo_ancho+"px";

        //Adjust image position > To keep it center
        var top = (alto*multiplicador)/2;
        var left = (ancho*multiplicador)/2;
        imagen.style.top="-"+top+"px";
        imagen.style.left="-"+left+"px";
    }
    if (inout==0) //onmouseout
    {
       //Recover the original image size
       imagen.style.height = alto+"px";
       imagen.style.width = ancho+"px";

       //Replace image
       imagen.style.top="0px";
       imagen.style.left="0px";
    }
}
```

I have not tested the code, but should point you to the right direction: Store the original image's dimensions when the image is in its original size and store them only once if possible. Hope it helps

Comment: You are my hero!! I did't realize that the onmouseout was changing the variables also >.<  THANKS

Answer (score 0):

`alto` and `ancho` values are being calculated every time you call `cambiar_img_ampliando` function. so `alto` and `ancho` values are updated with the modified image dimensions.

define `alto` and `ancho` outside `cambiar_img_ampliando` and assign values.

your code could be

```
var dims = {
    alto: {},
    ancho: {}
}

// function invoke 
cambiar_img_ampliando(imagen, inout, porcentaje, dims);
```

and inside your `cambiar_img_ampliando` function

```
if (inout == 1) { //onmouseover
    if (!dims.alto[image_id]) {
        dims.alto[image_id] = imagen.offsetHeight;
        dims.ancho[image_id] = imagen.offsetWidth;
    }
    // rest of the code
}

if (inout == 0) { //onmouseout
   //Recover the original image size
   imagen.style.height = dims.alto[image_id]+"px";
   imagen.style.width = dims.ancho[image_id]+"px";
   // rest of the code
}
```

Comment: @Venugopla: I think you are close enough but the `dims` have to be set only on the original image size. When the `mouseout` happens/is triggered, the image has already been scaled (from the `mouseover` code) and thus `offsetHeight` and `offsetWidth` are changed... I think...

Comment: @urban. true, based on your answer i improved mine to work on multiple images with different dimensions

Comment: That is cool! Actually, one could also store this info (the original dimensions) on the image DOM element (sth along the lines `this.dims = {w, h}`)... so there is no need for global variables in the page

Comment: @urban, that's perfect

Comment: @urban Declare unnecessary global variables affect performance ?

Comment: @ether82: I wouldn't think so but it pollutes the namespace, you must be sure you are not changing somebody's else data